# Terrafom 0.12.6 map variable with count interpolation

Tags: amazon-web-services, interpolation, terraform, hcl

I am trying to attach a list of policy ARN that I've been created as a map list. Please see below:

`variables.tf`:

```
variable "arns_map" {   type  = "map"
     default = {
    default       = [
      "default"
    ]
    bakery   = [    
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess"
    ]
    lambda = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess"
    ]
    media-server  = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticTranscoder_FullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
    ]
    recognition = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonESFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess"
    ]
    frontends = [
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudFrontFullAccess"
    ]
    elasticbeanstalk = [
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess"
    ]
    docker = [
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess"
    ]
    media = [
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      ]   } }
```

---

My resources are these ones:

main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "tenant_roles" {
  count = length(var.role_names)
  name  = element(var.role_names, count.index)
  description = "Dedicated role for tenants"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "${var.kops_nodes_role_arn}"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  tags  = {
    Managedby = "terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tenant_policies" {
  count       = length(values(var.arns_map))
  role        = join(",", keys(var.arns_map))
  # policy_arn  = element(var.role_names, count.index)
  policy_arn  = join(",", values(var.arns_map))

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role.tenant_roles,
  ]
}
```

---

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../../_platform_modules/roles/main.tf line 38, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tenant_policies":
  38:   policy_arn  = join(",", values(var.arns_map))
    |----------------
    | var.arns_map is map of list of string with 9 elements

Invalid value for "lists" parameter: incorrect list element type: string
required.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../../_platform_modules/roles/main.tf line 38, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tenant_policies":
  38:   policy_arn  = join(",", values(var.arns_map))
    |----------------
    | var.arns_map is map of list of string with 9 elements

Invalid value for "lists" parameter: incorrect list element type: string
required.
```

---

I am using terraform 0.12.6 to manage AWS resources.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's because `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` requires stringified arn's from `aws_iam_policy` resource as described in the [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) and you are trying to provide a `list(string)`.

I have limited experience with AWS IAM and I'm not sure about `role` parameter, but looks like you want to iterate over map. Like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tenant_policies" {
  count       = length(keys(var.arns_map))
  role        = element(keys(var.arns_map), count.index)
  policy_arn  = join(",", var.arns_map[element(keys(var.arns_maps), count.index))]
}
```

Also you can use local variables with it:

```
locals {
  arns_keys = keys(var.arns_map)
  arns_values = [for k in keys(var.arns_map) : join(",", var.arns_map[k])]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tenant_policies" {
  count       = length(local.arns_keys)
  role        = join(",", local.arns_keys)
  policy_arn  = element(local.arns_values, count.index)
}
```

Comment: Hi Andor,
Thank you very for your hints! Really appreciate that. But the policy_arn only accept one value not a list of string like below:

"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonESFullAccess,arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess,arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess"

What I am trying to achieve is calling the resource based on the number of arns_values and passing only on value to policy_arn.

I am still fencing problems with that.